# rpy2 loading R-dataframe in python produces wrong timestamps

Tags: python, r, pandas, timestamp, rpy2

I'm trying to load an R-dataframe into python using rpy2.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

robjects.r['load']("~/example.Rdata")
```

This produces a python dataframe with:

```
array(['times', 'all_data'], dtype='<U8')
```

However, the time values are shifted:

`robjects.r['times']` produces:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-12-31 17:00:00+00:00', '2014-12-31 17:30:00+00:00','2014-12-31 18:00:00+00:00', '2014-12-31 18:30:00+00:00', '2014-12-31 19:00:00+00:00', '2014-12-31 19:30:00+00:00', ...dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]']
```

when it should produce (below from R directly):

```
   "2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 00:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"
   "2015-01-01 01:30:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 02:00:00 UTC" "2015-01-01 02:30:00 UTC"
```

How do I retain the original correct UTC time when reading in this dataframe? Trying `x = pd.to_datetime(robjects.r['times'])` also produces the same incorrect timestamps in the python dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing

```
robjects.r['load']("~/example.Rdata")
```

the R object(s) serialiazed in the file `example.Rdata` end up being loaded and bound to symbols in R's "global environment". That does not presumably result in a Python Dataframe `array(['times', 'all_data'], dtype='<U8')`.

The Python code

```
robjects.r['times']
```

could also be written as

```
robjects.globalenv['times']
```

and what it does is retrieve the R symbol `times` in R's global environment and pass it through the rpy2 conversion.

It hard to ascertain what is exactly going on without a self-contained reproducible example, but if this seems to be be an issue with rpy2, open one on the issue tracker.

**edit:** Issue opened here - https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/634

Comment: Thanks. I tried the globalenv suggestion but it still produces the same incorrect timestamps. Saving the R-dataframe as a csv and reading it in via pandas produces the correct timestamps so I will check if this is an rpy2 issue.

Comment: I edited the answer a minute or so after entering it. There is a any issue (not sure it is your issue without reproducible example on your end), and I already have a PR in progress (see the link in the answer).